# Higher buttons in lay-out

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I have 4 buttons in the bottom of my layout, and I want them a tiny bit higher placed than they are at the moment.

I changed the sizes and margins and all, but that doesn't seem to work. They get placed like a lot higher and not just small bits.

Like in the image i show, on the left one, the buttons in the bottom of the screen are placed correctly, in the right one one, they are too low. What code do I need to change to solve that, and let them become the same?

[Klik hier om de afbeelding te bekijken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5D9v.png)

This is the xml code from the left picture, where the buttons are placed correctly:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Contact" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
 </FrameLayout>

     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:autoLink="web" />

</ScrollView>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the right page, bezoekpage, where the buttons are too low:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek"> 


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
 </FrameLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/title_activity_bezoek"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
    />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Klik hier voor de uitgebreide bezoektijden."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you really want ? add image with your desired result?

Comment: I copied your second layout file and checked it,  the buttons are placed higher exactly the way you wanted.

Comment: Sohail Zahid, when you click on the picture you see 2 screens. The left one, has 4 buttons on the buttom, just a bit from the entire bottom of the screen. The right one has the same buttons, but they are placed lower on the screen. I want them to be the same height.

Answer (score 0):

First stop giving fix height and width to your layout it creates problem for multiple size devices.Follow a good tutorial or book for beginning android.

In first layout you define scroll height fix to 364.
in second layout the text view and linearlayout has combined height 280+95=375 and including textview margintop=30dp it become 405. thats why your layout button is at the bottom.
use scrollview in second layout also with height 364.that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i corrected your code.. please make this answer  as right if its helpful

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
    </FrameLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_bezoek"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Klik hier voor de uitgebreide bezoektijden."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Facebook" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Youtube" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Twitter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="LinkedIn" />

</LinearLayout>
```